# Convert Local time into Long format from openweather Api

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp, openweathermap

I obtained data from open weather API

```
dt:1679888142
timezone:7200
```

I'm trying to change UNIX time into local time by applying `Date` object in JavaScript followed by `toUTCString()` to get the local time.

The goal is to change the obtained local time `'Mon, 27 Mar 2023 05:35:42 GMT'` into long formatted time eg `'Monday, March 27 at 4:35 AM'`. when i apply the following code, its not formatting also adding my timezone difference to it

this is the following code

```
  let epochtime = weatherData.dt;
  let timezone = weatherData.timezone;
  const rfc2822Date = new Date((epochtime + timezone) * 1000).toUTCString();

  const options = {
    weekday: "long",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    hour12: true
  };
const longFormatDateTime =  rfc2822Date.toLocaleString("en-us",options);
```

i tried to pass the date once again into date object which will result in gmt+timezone and format. formatting seems to work but local time is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we're dealing with a fixed offset here, we can simply add the UTC offset in seconds to the epoch time when creating a Date object. We need to specify the 'UTC' timezone when formatting however, to avoid formatting in the client's timezone.

```js
function formatUnixTime(epochTime, utcOffsetSeconds, options = {}) {
  const date = new Date((epochTime + utcOffsetSeconds) * 1000);
  return date.toLocaleTimeString([], { timeZone: 'UTC', ...options });
}

function getLongFormatUnixTime(epochTime, utcOffsetSeconds) {
  const options = { weekday: 'long', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true };
  return formatUnixTime(epochTime, utcOffsetSeconds, options);
}

const weatherData = { 
  dt: 1679888142,
  timezone: 7200
}
 
const epochTime = weatherData.dt;
const utcOffset = weatherData.timezone;
 
console.log('Unix time:     ', epochTime);
console.log('UTC Offset (s):', utcOffset);
console.log('Time (UTC):    ', getLongFormatUnixTime(epochTime, 0));
console.log('Time (in zone):', getLongFormatUnixTime(epochTime, utcOffset));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `toLocaleString` directly on the date object not the rfc2822 string. I recommend implementing it like this

```
  let epochtime = weatherData.dt;
  let timezone = weatherData.timezone;
  const UNIXDate = new Date((epochtime + timezone) * 1000);

  const options = {
    weekday: "long",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    hour12: true
  };

const longFormatDateTime =  UNIXDate.toLocaleString("en-us",options);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: its not working. let me rephrase, im trying to get the local time of a particular place. The above code you mentioned is giving me the local time of my place (which is already gmt+5:30) and its adding offset time by 2hrs , so altogther its offset by 7.5hrs instead of 2hrs